# C3js: Multi Color line in a single data

Tags: javascript, html, css, c3.js

I have C3.js line chart and I have implemented some custom design changes in it, and which is working fine till now.
I'm unable to achieve the following design changes in it:

**a) Multicolor lines for different points. (For example from my chart below: 100-200: color:red, 200-100: color: blue, 100-400: color: orange, 400-150: color: pink, 150-250: color: green, 250-120 : color: brown, 120-200: color: black;)**

**b) I want partial color gradient on it i.e from my current data below 100 it should be white.**

P.S I'm attaching one sample image also as an expectation for better understanding. For point "a": I have marked with a red ink and for a point "b": I have marked with a black pen.
Thanks in advance.
[Expected Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AAUt.jpg)

```js
var grad1 =
  '<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">' +
  '  <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#E6ECFF;stop-opacity:1" />' +
  '  <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:#E6ECFF;stop-opacity:1" />' +
  '  <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#E6ECFF;stop-opacity:1" />' +
  '</linearGradient>';


var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['sample', 100, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 120, 200]
    ],
    types: {
      sample: 'area'
    },
    colors: {
      sample: 'url(#grad1)'
    }
  },
  oninit: function() {
    this.svg[0][0].getElementsByTagName('defs')[0].innerHTML += grad1;
  },
  grid: {
    x: {
      show: false
    },
    y: {
      show: true
    }

  },
  point: {
    r: 5
  },

});
```

```css
.c3 .c3-axis-x path,
.c3 .c3-axis-x line {
  stroke: #052f5f1a;
}

.c3-axis-y text,
.c3-axis-x text {
  fill: #052F5F;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.c3 .c3-axis-y path,
.c3 .c3-axis-y line {
  display: none;
}

circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: #501DF8 !important;
}

.c3 g.c3-shapes.c3-lines path {
  stroke: #5850D6 !important;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.c3-grid line {
  stroke: #052F5F;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.c3-xgrid-focus {
  stroke: #979797 !important;
  stroke-dasharray: 5, 5;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.11/c3.css" integrity="sha512-VYsPnk6xiH1iL282B+F0FfCXy+C4LJIXpzdYQUa3fG7iyeFFLHkuM9cOXYouDkOHOANGuBtxFjPg3DloZBO6eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Can [this](https://c3js.org/samples/options_color.html) help you?

Comment: @xKobalt Hi!
Thanks for the help. But these are of different color lines. I'm expecting multicolor line in single data itself.
Please check the sample image attached.